# how to convert string array to MySQL IN clause

Tags: java, mysql

```
String[] name = request.getParameterValues("name");

 name stored as ['anil,raju,anitha']
```

how to convert it to

```
            'anil','raju','anitha'
```

here my code

```
        List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(name);  

  for (String e : wordList)  
  {  
     System.out.println(e);  
  }
```

please help me to get expected output

Comment: Be very careful. User input (such as request parameters) needs to be validated before you use it in a query.

Answer (score 2):

This has been quite a while ago, so here are some updated examples:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class JoiningTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] test = { "word1", "word2", "word3"};

        String join = String.join(",", test);
        System.out.println(join);

        String collect = Stream.of(test).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
        System.out.println(collect);
    }

}
```

Which will print:

```
word1,word2,word3
word1,word2,word3
```

Use apache commons lang:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] test = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
        String inClause = StringUtils.join(test, ",");
        System.out.println(inClause);
}
```

Prints:

```
1,2,3,4
```

Or the new StringJoiner (for your prefix/suffix):

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("','","'", "'");
        for(String s: test)
            joiner.add(s);

        System.out.println(joiner.toString());
```

Prints:

```
'1','2','3','4'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Stringbuilder` like:

```
Iterator<String> itr = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(names)).iterator();

    while(itr.hasNext()) {

    sb.append("'").append(itr.next()).append("'");

        if(itr.hasNext()) {
            sb.append(",");
        }
    }
System.out.println(sb.toString);
```

Comment: You forgot the `,` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] name = {"anil","raju","anitha"};
String nameConcate = "" ;
for(int i = 0 ; i < name.length ; i++){
   nameConcate +="'"+name[i]+"',";
}
nameConcate=nameConcate.substring(0,nameConcate.length()-1);
```